# PHP check if file exists in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-io

I am wanting to check if a video file exists on my server - if it does embed it else play the youtube embed instead.

(Local file and youtube urls are stored in separate Custom Fields, both are absolute paths)

I have the following code which based off other similar questions and the php manual seems to be correct however I always get the local video player embedded regardless of if the local file exists or not - cant for the life of me figure out what is wrong?

```
   <?php
        $localvideo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videoembed', true);
        if ( file_exists($localvideo)) {
            //embed video url stored in custom field 'videoembed'
            echo do_shortcode( '[video src='. $localvideo . ' ]');
        } else {
            //code to embed youtube video instead
            //echo to test if url in variable is correct
            echo $localvideo; 

        }
        clearstatcache();
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you check & post value of `$localvideo` ?

Comment: Yeah. Given that you're using $localvideo as a src—something that should be a URL—is it possible that it's a web url rather than an actual file? And if it *is* a URL, does the URL "exist"? (This might mean it's there and serving a 404, for example—I don't know what file_exists does in that case...) Apart from the possible confusion between files and URLs—I'd have expected your code to perhaps check for a file to exist, then to serve a URL to it—I don't see much wrong there.

Comment: Have added echo of $localvideo and displays the web url ie 'http://localhost/wp-content/video/myvid.flv'

Comment: Maybe the previous result has been cached? Try insert clearstatcache() to clear the cache.

Comment: I have it already just before the end of the closing php tag

Comment: And does that web URL "exist"? I'm not sure how file_exists handles URLs. If it serves a "not found" page—which it seems to do on my WP install—that might still technically count as "exists" to the URL wrapper functionality in file_exists. On a separate note, why are you setting the post meta to a URL that may not exist? Wouldn't it be simpler just not to set the post meta in the first place, if the video isn't there?

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback - the reason for the setup is i have a kiosk style machine in my movie store allowing access to my website, however the line speed isn't sufficient to stream youtube when others are using the network a lot so would like to say "IF local video file exists on this machine (running a virtual server) THEN embed that file but if i haven't downloaded the file THEN stream from youtube...in past got this to work with WP using is_user_logged_in but this didnt first check to see if the file exists. Will check re your suggestion of Not Found page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that the file_exists string needed to be a relative path to the file without the preceding /
ie my original file_exist check was effectively

```
$localvideo = 'http://localhost/wp-content/video/test.flv'
```

instead of

```
$localvideo = 'wp-content/video/test.flv'
```

Answer (score 0):

change file_exists to is_file()
in your code
for example:
if ( is_file($localvideo)) {